# I am unable to rename the files to a single format as the file names are unique

Tags: python, regex, shell, file-rename

I have below set of files to be renamed in a single format as shown here;

```
ABCD.R9999.COMMON.D170401.T199665.txt
```

Here, `ABCD` is mandatory on all files at its beginning. And Any content comes like `RR5526` or `AB8673` needs to be replaced with `R9999`.

Then crop all other unwanted fields and rename the file with above mentioned format.

```
DH_062_FAT_HSC_H1666_EFTO.FH1666.COMMON.D170801.T0433417
DH_062_FAT_MMA_H0927_EFTO.FH0927.COMMON.D170801.T0433417
ABCD.FH2237.COMMON.D170701.T1549353
P.FH5526.COMMON.D130501.T1243225
FS3389.COMMON.D160901.T1539489
P.FH5587.COMMON.D150601.T1529158.7073202
EFTO.FH3890.COMMON.D170401.T1332005
H1737.COMMON.R201602.D160201.T1725587.txt                 
EFTO.RH3864.MSPCOBMA.D170421.T1246176
P.FH2225.COMMON.D170101.T1737084.12016373.txt
P.FH3204.COMMON.D170701.T1549353.txt_20170627_133012.txt
P.RH2312.COMMON.D110301.T1539063.13313178.txt.gz
```

I have tried below script to crop filenames;

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=/path/to/*COMMON*
for i in $FILES
do
  newarg="$(echo "$i" | sed 's/.FH\d{4}.COMMON.D\d{6}')"
  if [ "$newarg" != "" ];then
    mv "$i" "$newarg" 
  fi
done
```

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: This sounds like a job for [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). What happens to names like `EFTO.RH3864.MSPCOBMA.D170421.T1246176` that don't contain `.COMMON.` ?

Comment: Filenames with MSPCOBMA is a different set of files. That can be handled once I have an idea about how to handle first case.

I tried directly renaming using regex. Updated the post above. But I am not good at RegEx :(

Comment: You still should post that code, even though it doesn't do exactly what you want (otherwise you're likely to get more downvotes). So post the code, and explain what it does wrong. You should also post the output you expect from that input.

Comment: @codeforester, I got a script which replace filenames. I have added the same in my post now. I am not good at RegEx. and I dint find a way to replace the filenames as I am expecting. :(

Comment: @PM2Ring, I have added the code I have. I need help to create a RegEx which replace the unique filenames to a custom one as mentioned in the post.

Comment: I've written some code which _may_ do what you want, but I can't be sure without seeing your expected output. I think the first 2 names in your list both map to `ABCD.R9999.COMMON.D170801.T0433417.txt`. Is that correct? Also, you haven't described what happens to names that already end in `.txt` or `.txt.gz`.

Comment: @PM2Ring, The expected names of files is as below;

ABCD.R9999.COMMON.D170401.T199665.txt

here, ABCD is a common for all files.

R9999 is the client ID to be replaced.

All other values 'COMMON.D170401.T199665' should be same. We should not change it. "D170401.T199665" is unique for each file. So it needs to be fetched from same file.

Regarding txt and gz you can ignore. I can rename and add those extensions by my own at later point of time.

Comment: You want all the filenames to be changed to `ABCD.R9999.COMMON.D170401.T199665.txt`? Sorry, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @PM2Ring; Regarding below listed files;

`DH_062_FAT_HSC_H1666_EFTO.FH1666.COMMON.D170801.T0433417`
`DH_062_FAT_MMA_H0927_EFTO.FH0927.COMMON.D170801.T0433417`

These are 2 different files. We should rename it as an extra file.

Comment: @PM2Ring, No. `COMMON.D170401.T199665` is a unique value for each file. It is different for each file. 

In expected output, the fields which is common is `ABCD.R9999.COMMON` only. 

The next field which starts with D is the date. and field which starts with T is the file's metadata. It is different for each file.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code that does what I think you want to do, although your description is still not completely clear.

```
import re

data = '''\
DH_062_FAT_HSC_H1666_EFTO.FH1666.COMMON.D170801.T0433417
DH_062_FAT_MMA_H0927_EFTO.FH0927.COMMON.D170801.T0433417
ABCD.FH2237.COMMON.D170701.T1549353
P.FH5526.COMMON.D130501.T1243225
FS3389.COMMON.D160901.T1539489
P.FH5587.COMMON.D150601.T1529158.7073202
EFTO.FH3890.COMMON.D170401.T1332005
H1737.COMMON.R201602.D160201.T1725587.txt
EFTO.RH3864.MSPCOBMA.D170421.T1246176
P.FH2225.COMMON.D170101.T1737084.12016373.txt
P.FH3204.COMMON.D170701.T1549353.txt_20170627_133012.txt
P.RH2312.COMMON.D110301.T1539063.13313178.txt.gz
'''.splitlines()

pat = re.compile(r'(?:.*)(\.COMMON\..*$)')

for s in data:
    z = pat.sub(r'ABCD.R9999\1', s)
    if '.txt' not in z:
        z += '.txt'
    print(' In: {!r}\nOut: {!r}\n'.format(s, z))
```

**output**

```
 In: 'DH_062_FAT_HSC_H1666_EFTO.FH1666.COMMON.D170801.T0433417'
Out: 'ABCD.R9999.COMMON.D170801.T0433417.txt'

 In: 'DH_062_FAT_MMA_H0927_EFTO.FH0927.COMMON.D170801.T0433417'
Out: 'ABCD.R9999.COMMON.D170801.T0433417.txt'

 In: 'ABCD.FH2237.COMMON.D170701.T1549353'
Out: 'ABCD.R9999.COMMON.D170701.T1549353.txt'

 In: 'P.FH5526.COMMON.D130501.T1243225'
Out: 'ABCD.R9999.COMMON.D130501.T1243225.txt'

 In: 'FS3389.COMMON.D160901.T1539489'
Out: 'ABCD.R9999.COMMON.D160901.T1539489.txt'

 In: 'P.FH5587.COMMON.D150601.T1529158.7073202'
Out: 'ABCD.R9999.COMMON.D150601.T1529158.7073202.txt'

 In: 'EFTO.FH3890.COMMON.D170401.T1332005'
Out: 'ABCD.R9999.COMMON.D170401.T1332005.txt'

 In: 'H1737.COMMON.R201602.D160201.T1725587.txt'
Out: 'ABCD.R9999.COMMON.R201602.D160201.T1725587.txt'

 In: 'EFTO.RH3864.MSPCOBMA.D170421.T1246176'
Out: 'EFTO.RH3864.MSPCOBMA.D170421.T1246176.txt'

 In: 'P.FH2225.COMMON.D170101.T1737084.12016373.txt'
Out: 'ABCD.R9999.COMMON.D170101.T1737084.12016373.txt'

 In: 'P.FH3204.COMMON.D170701.T1549353.txt_20170627_133012.txt'
Out: 'ABCD.R9999.COMMON.D170701.T1549353.txt_20170627_133012.txt'

 In: 'P.RH2312.COMMON.D110301.T1539063.13313178.txt.gz'
Out: 'ABCD.R9999.COMMON.D110301.T1539063.13313178.txt.gz'
```

I'll let you figure out how to handle names that map to the same output string.

---

Here's a version that only retains the `D` and `T` parts of the name.

```
pat = re.compile(r'(?:.*)\.COMMON\..*?(D\d*\.T\d*).*$')

for s in data:
    z = pat.sub(r'ABCD.R9999.COMMON.\1.txt', s)
    print(' In: {!r}\nOut: {!r}\n'.format(s, z))
```

Comment: I just checked with the requirement;

We need to replace FH1666 with RH1666. This means, the value `H1666` will be different for each file and anything before H**** should be replaced with R.

Comment: The code you have shared will be replacing those fields if it is a file content right ?.

Those are the files which I am working with and the filenames needs to be replaced as the output you shared. How do we change it ?.

Comment: My code creates new strings from the strings you supply it. It doesn't know that those strings are file names. Once you have the names there are various ways to use them to rename the files, and if you have problems doing that please ask a fresh question; file renaming is a different topic to string pattern matching & replacement.